# How to create rootfs for user mode Linux on Fedora 18?

Tags: linux, non-root-user, systemd, user-mode-linux

I want to create a rootfs to be used with an UML kernel and be able to use the internet. I was using `febootstrap` with packages: `bash`, `coreutils`, `net-tools`, `iputils`. After using `febootstrap-supermin-helper` I got my `rootfs` but when trying to boot it with UML I get these errors:

```
[    4.340000] systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
[    4.340000] systemd[1]: dbus.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
[    4.340000] systemd-logind[638]: Failed to get system D-Bus connection: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
[    4.340000] systemd-logind[638]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection refused
```

I am wondering which packages are necessary for `rootfs` and if there is any other way besides `febootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try PRoot (http://proot.me) as an alternative to UML.  Both are based on ptrace(2), although PRoot does not require any setup to get internet access from the guest system:

```
host$ proot -R ./fedora-18-x86_64/ bash
guest$ wget http://google.fr
...
```

where "./fedora-18-x86_64/" is the content of a rootfs downloaded from http://download.openvz.org/template/precreated/

Answer (score 0):

**Buildroot**

The `qemu_x86_64_defconfig` defconfig almost worked, except that I had to add `::sysinit:/sbin/mdev -s` to the `inittab`. I think this is because Buildroot relies on `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT` to create `/dev`.

Rootfs:

```
git clone git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
cd buildroot
git checkout 2017.02
make qemu_x86_64_defconfig

# Custom inittab.
echo 'BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY="rootfs_overlay"' >>.config
make olddefconfig
mkdir -p rootfs_overlay/etc
printf '
::sysinit:/bin/mount -t proc proc /proc
::sysinit:/bin/mount -o remount,rw /
::sysinit:/bin/mkdir -p /dev/pts
::sysinit:/bin/mkdir -p /dev/shm
::sysinit:/bin/mount -a
::sysinit:/sbin/mdev -s
::sysinit:/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -n -L console 0 vt100
::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot
::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcK
::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
' > rootfs_overlay/etc/inittab

# Build image.
make BR2_JLEVEL=$(($(nproc)-2))
cp output/images/rootfs.ext2 /path/to/linux
```

Then on kernel source:

```
cd /path/to/linux
git checkout v4.9
make mrproper
make defconfig ARCH=um
make ARCH=um
./linux eth0=tuntap,,,192.168.0.254
```

Now you are inside the VM, and you can leave with:

```
poweroff
```

The filesystem is persistent, try it out with:

```
date >f
```

and reboot.

TODO get network working. The current `eth0=` is just a dummy to prevent Buildroot's init from stalling waiting for the network device.

You can also step debug the kernel as shown at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943857/linux-kernel-live-debugging-how-its-done-and-what-tools-are-used/44669413#44669413

TODO I don't know how to deal with kernel modules, since they must be compiled against the UML, not x86. The first problem is that `insmod` will fail because UML does not have `SMP` which affects `vermagic`, and if you force vermagic, weird things happen like `printk` does not print anything. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488625/user-mode-linux-installing-a-module-error

You can also inspect that image with QEMU if you prefer:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -M pc -kernel output/images/bzImage -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw -append root=/dev/vda -net nic,model=virtio -net user
```

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0 host.